# jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице подключен jQuery UI Datepicker:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date").datepicker();
});
</script>
<input id="#date">
```

`$(document).ready(function(){` - означает что скрипт ожидает пока страница загрузится, ну если у меня очень большая страница, и она может грузится например 5 сек. а я хочу использовать календарь сразу не ожидая полной загрузки страницы, то как изменить скрипт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id='date'>
<script>
    $("#date").datepicker();
</script>
```

вроде так :-)

Comment: +1, только имхо глупая идея у ТС...

Comment: @thunder да почему глупая? Может нужно-то всего лишь только этот элемент прикрутить. Костыль-то конечно не хорошо, но и перебирать движок тоже не хочется :-)

Comment: да я так делал не работало, не заметил порядок, у меня сначало JS файл подключался а потом уже input... если  $(document).ready(function(){ - тогда не важно, а если без него то имеет суть...
спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пиши без `ready`, никто ж не запрещает, но последствия могут быть не предсказуемыми... В частности поле `<input..>` может не успеть загрузиться, тогда скрипт не будет работать... Может не проинициализироваться сам jQuery... Да много что может случиться... ИМХО может имеет смысл подумать над уменьшением размера страницы.